# Ajax with method load() for options value in select field

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a problem with my select field, because I can't catch the value of an option, my code:

```
<form method="get" name="form1" > 
  <select id="rpc" onchange="$('#rpc').load('aja.province.php?cod=this.value')">
```

how can I send the value to the option in a PHP file with method GET?

Best Regards.

Comment: Where is your code? Please post that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$('#rpc').load('aja.province.php?cod=this.value')` should be `$('#rpc').load('aja.province.php?cod='+this.value)`.

`this.value` is not a string, it is a javascript expression.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using jQuery, I would suggest removing the inline stuff and just do something like this in your source:

```
$('#rpc').change( function () {
    var url = 'aja.province.php?cod=' + this.value;
    load(url, function () {
        // do whatever you need to do with returned value
    }
});
```

Note that your current in-line `load()` call is passing a literal string of `this.value` for the `cod` parameter.